# Como concatenar data no sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho um campo onde é gravado a data e hora:

```
'2013-06-13 00:00:01' and '2013-06-13 11:59:59'
```

Quero fazer uma consulta passando a data e uma hora fixa:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(getdate()  AS DATETIME), 111) + '00:00:01' and
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(getdate()  AS DATETIME), 111) + '11:59:59'
```

Como eu poderia concatenar estas informações?
agradeço

Comment: Resolveu seu problemas?

Comment: sim, até o momento agradeço a ajuda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seria isso.

```
SUADATA between CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(getdate()  AS DATE), 101) + ' 00:00:01' AS DATETIME) 
AND  CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(getdate()  AS DATE), 101) + ' 11:59:59'AS DATETIME)
```